# Chamada de javascript condicional em html5

Tags: javascript, html5

Como posso chamar um script obedecendo uma condicional em html5?

Por exemplo, dependendo do endereço no navegador ele carrega determinado script

Se o endereço for http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/ carrega o seguinte script:

```
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Se o endereço for http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/dispensacao/ carrega o seguinte script:

```
<script  src="dispensacao/js/index.js"></script>
```

Se o endereço for http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/hinario/ carrega o seguinte script:

```
<script  src="hinarioCatado/js/index.js"></script>
```

e assim por diante com vários ifs

Obrigado!

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67951/discussion-on-question-by-miguel-silva-chamada-de-javascript-condicional-em-html)

Comment: Ok, desculpe,  realmente ficou longa a discussão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que não queres usar vários arquivos index, a solução passa por utilizar parâmetros no url.

Exemplos  `index.htm?id=audioplayer` `index.htm?id=dispensacao` `index.htm?id=hinario`

```
//location.search retorna a parte querystring de um URL, incluindo o ponto de interrogação (?)
//.split divide o url em duas partes, uma antes do ? e outra depois do ?

var variaveis=location.search.split("?");

//variaveis[1] é a parte depois do ? que será quebrada em duas partes, uma antes de = e outra depois de =

var quebra = variaveis[1].split("=");

//quebra[1] é a segunda parte, depois de = que corresponde ao valor do parametro passado na url
//de posse desse valor é só fazer a verificação e chamar o js correspondente

if (quebra[1]=="audioplayer"){
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"><\/script>');
} else if (quebra[1]=="dispensacao") {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="dispensacao.js"><\/script>');
} else if (quebra[1]=="hinario") {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="hinario.js"><\/script>');
}else{
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"><\/script>');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tente:

```
const URL1 = "http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/";
const URL2 = "http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/dispensacao/";
const URL3 = "http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/hinario/";

let url = window.location.href;

if ( url === URL1) {
    include("js/index.js");
}else if ( url === URL2) {
    include("dispensacao/js/index.js");
}else if (url === URL3 ) {
    include("hinarioCatado/js/index.js");
}

function include(file) {

    let script  = document.createElement('script');
    script.src  = file;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.defer = true;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Assim que chegar em casa faço um teste.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @Bruno Morales

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!